# all vhost are pointing to single localtion in openSuse 12.3

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, opensuse

I have a virtual host setup for development on my local machine a.local, now I'm adding another vhost b.local, I created another vhost file in /etc/apache2/vhosts.d/ as b.local.conf.
When I access http://b.local/ it goes to a.local. I'm not able to find the reason for it :(.

a.local points to /home/sharique/project/a/webroot

b.local points to /home/sharique/project/b/webroot

Entries in hosts file

127.0.0.1 a.local

127.0.0.1 b.local

Comment: Please read our [about] page, there is specific information relating to your configuration and usage in it. Then consider whether [so] or [su] is the correct place to ask.

Comment: Have you restarted httpd? Does grepping for a.local under /etc/apache2 only match the vhost file or is it specifically included in some other file?

Comment: what is the output of httpd -S

Comment: @ptman, I restarted apache,
The output of httpd -S is syntax ok. No error shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `NameVirtualHost *:80` to `NameVirtualHost *` - The reason for this is because with `*:80`, apache will match the first virtualhost named `*:80`. With just `*`, apache will match HTTP_HOST against `ServerName` directive, provided you set that.